# Attempting to login to a rest api with ajax

Tags: ajax, restful-authentication

The api documentation describes the format for the url as well as the json formatting... However, I have been unsuccessful in my post. Any ideas what I am missing?

API Documentation tidbits:

POST /api/rest/auth/login

username   string
password   string
Sample:
{
  "username" : "john", 
  "password" : "mySecretPassword" 
}

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: "serverhost:port/database/api/rest/auth/login/",
data: {
"username": "username",
'password': "password",
},
dataType: "json",
success: function (){
alert("Thanks")}
});
```

The response states that the user is not logged in. My response to that is ns, that's what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: What API are you trying to log in to? Can you link us to documentation of it? Also, can you post the exact response that you got?

Comment: Thanks for your help, It is a private database so I am unable to link the docs. I have updated the question with the info that is offered in the documents though. Also, the response now is error code 500... when I open the link, it says the document is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is correct, but try this for the data object:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "serverhost:port/database/api/rest/auth/login/",
    data: '{"username": "username", "password": "password"}',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (){
        alert("Thanks")
    }
});
```

I really don't know if this will work but it worked on this one project I was working on and every other format didn't work.